# RavenDB: how to write queries on grandchildren?

Tags: c#, nested, ravendb, hierarchy

Given the following C# code below, I am trying to retrieve all the continents having provinces whose cities include:

1. a city with Name and Address respectively set to "Aloma" and "123" and
2. another city with Name and Address respectively set to "Hemane" and "435".

---

```
public class Continent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries{ get; set; }
}

public class Countries
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Province> Provinces{ get; set; }
}

public class Province
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Province> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address   { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to use the query below, but it does not seem to work. Can you please help me?

```
Expression<Func<Province, bool>> matchCities = rec =>
      (rec.Cities.Count(fi => fi.Name == "Aloma" && fi.Address== "123") > 0)
        && (rec.Cities.Count(fj => fj.Name == "Hemane" && fj.Address== "435") > 0);

Func<Province, bool> funcMatchCities= matchCities.Compile();

var results3 = session.Query<Continent>()
                      .Where(top => top.Countries.Any(ta => ta.Province.Any(
                                  rec => funcMatchCities(rec))))
                      .OfType<Continent>()
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query it like so:

```
var results3 = session.Query<Continent>()
                      .Where(top => top.Countries.Any(ta => ta.Province.Any(
                                 rec =>
      (rec.Fields.Any(fi => fi.Name == "Aloma" && fi.Address== "123") )
        && (rec.Fields.Any(fj => fj.Name == "Hemane" && fj.Address== "435") )))
                      .OfType<Continent>()
                      .ToList();
```

Note that you cannot `Compile` expression when you send them to the linq provider.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Your query works when it finds a Province having the cities "Aloma" and "Hemane". But it also works when it finds a first Province with a city named "Aloma" and another Province with a city named "Hemane", while neither of these two provinces both include the two cities. How can I prevent the query from working in the second case?

Comment: So, how to make the following work: var query = session.Query<Continent>() .Where(top => top.Countries.Any(ta => ta.Provinces.Any( rec => (rec.Cities.Where(fi => fi.Name == "Aloma" && fi.Address == "123") .Intersect() && rec.Cities.Where(fj => fj.Name == "Hemane" && fj.Address == "435"))))) .OfType<Continent>() .ToList();